# Include class files and assembly names in .NET6 upgraded project

Tags: c#, upgrade, .net-6.0

I'm upgrading my  project from `.netframework` v4.6.2 to `.net6` via [upgrade-assistant](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant/tutorial/install-upgrade-assistant). 
 Once the .csproj file are upgraded from classic to sdk style the class files, the assemblies and the nuget packages included in the .csproj file were removed.
However the nuget packages are added under `<packagereference />` and are available in the sdk style .csproj file. 
How are the class files and the assemblies are being included/mapped for compilation in a `.net6` csproj file.

Below is a typical comparison between a sdk style to a classic `.csproj` file.

[image: SDK_vs_Classic]

In the above screenshot, I had done a simple project upgrade with a WPF app with `caliburn.micro` dependent packages from `.netframework` v4.6.2 to `.net6` using VS2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line at the top of your file `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` says that it should use that Sdk to build your project. This leads to importing a whole host of other files located in the versioned SDK folder of your computer (`%ProgramFiles%dotnet\sdk\<version>\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk`).

This will eventually include a file called `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.props`.

There's a specific itemgroup that does all the magic which (simplified) looks like this:

```xml
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(EnableDefaultItems)' == 'true' ">
    <Compile Include="**/*.cs" Condition=" '$(EnableDefaultCompileItems)' == 'true' " />
  </ItemGroup>
```

All of your separate `Compile` items are now covered by the glob and can be removed from the new SDK csproj. Since you are using WPF, you are actually using a different SDK that includes targets for WindowsDesktop which does more things like nesting the .xaml.cs files under the .xaml files and includes specific XAML compilation operations.

I recommend using [MSBuild Structured Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) if you want to investigate MSBuild further.

Comment: Even without adding the above mentioned line, the sdk style loads the class files into the project. From where its getting mapped?

Comment: Which line? The project specifying the SDK or the compile glob? Without the SDK you don't have a project that will compile. The compile glob is included by default. You can't see it but you _can_ turn it off. You can either set `EnableDefaultItems` to false or set `EnableDefaultCompileItems` to false.